# применение requests и threading (python)

Tags: python, многопоточность, requests

Я пишу программу, которая возвращает мне случайный адрес в заданном округе. Мне бы хотелось ускорить ее с помощью модуля threading. Я попробовал сделать это так:

```
from threading import Thread
import random
import requests


maxx = 49
minx = 32.5

maxy = -69
miny = -124  

key = "<key>"
geo_base = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address="

ocean_id = "ChIJ_7hu48qBWgYRT1MQ81ciNKY"

def get_random_adress():

    x = random.uniform(minx, maxx)
    y = random.uniform(miny, maxy)

    res = requests.get(geo_base + str(x) + "," + str(y) + key)

    adress = ""

    
    if res.json() != {'results': [], 'status': 'ZERO_RESULTS'} and res.json()['results'][0]['place_id'] != ocean_id:
        components = res.json()['results'][0]['address_components']
        for component in components:
            adress += component['short_name'] + " "

        return adress

    else:
        return 0


def main():
    while True:
        print (get_random_adress())


threads = []
for i in range(10):
    t = Thread(target=main)
    threads.append(t)
    threads[i].run()
```

К сожалению, это код не ускорило. Как я понимаю, просто так модуль requests не работает в нескольких потоках одновременно. Как я могу это исправить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Забудьте о том, что я написал ранее, для использования потоков и многопоточности и запуска сразу нескольких разных функций или одной и той же - не обязательно использовать асинхронность.

Вы просто неправильно запускали поток.

> Решение: Вместо `threads[i].run()` в цикле написать `threads[i].start()`

Comment: При запуске кода возникла ошибка: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'main' was never awaited
  self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback

Comment: Отредактировал.

Comment: Да, с threads[i].start() действительно все заработало. А можно поинтересоваться разницей между run и start?

Comment: Надо только потом ещё `join` сделать всем потокам, а то с завершением программы все потоки поубиваются сразу, не дожидаясь окончания.

Comment: Несмотря на различие яп, первый ответ остается актуальным - [ссылка] (https://coderoad.ru/8579657/%D0%92-%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B4%D1%83-Thread-start-%D0%B8-Runnable-run)

Comment: @ILRK `run` - это то, как сам поток запускает то, что вы ему передали в `target`. Вызывать `run` - это как если бы вы непосредственно вызвали `main` сами, поток при этом был использован только как переменная, содержащая имя вашего метода. А вот `start` запускает собственно сам поток, который уже в свою очередь запустит ваш `main`.

Comment: Понял, спасибо.